# What would be the best textbook you can ever recommend to achieve algebra skills?

Tags: book-recommendation

I think that I'm not familiar with algebra, which consequently made me look for a book to achieve algebra skills. Do you have any advise?

Here are given what I'll be asked

> Polynomials, Logarithmic functions, division, Rational Numbers,
>   Inequalities, Absolute values, exponentials, radicals, Factoring,
>   first degree equations, sets, functions, second degree equations,
>   parabolas, complex numbers.

Regards!

Comment: Algebra at what level?

Comment: @Brahadeesh High school. I'm preparing for exams.

Comment: Can you mention a few topics that you are expected to study for the exams? Such information will help you get relevant and broad suggestions.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Polynomials, Logarithmic functions, division, Rational Numbers, Inequalities, Absolute values, exponentials, radicals, Factoring, first degree equations, sets, functions, second degree equations, parabolas,complex numbers.

Comment: Do add these details into the body of the question for better visibility :)

Comment: @Brahadeesh See the new edit. I also want to learn everything, perhaps impossible but am just giving it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80912/discussion-between-brahadeesh-and-enzo).

Comment: There are many free resources on the web that will heip you learn or relearn this material. I suggest you search to find those that just match your current level of knowledge. Working problems will stretch you. Look for sites that suit your learning style.

Comment: There is no "best textbook" I would "ever" recommend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend the *Little Mathematics Library* series of Mir Publishers. Some of the titles in the series that will be particularly relevant for you are:

1. A. G. Kurosh - Algebraic Equations of Arbitrary Degrees
2. A. I. Markushevich - Areas and Logarithms
3. P. P. Korovkin - Inequalities

They do cover more material than may be required from the point of view of your exams, but they are wonderful to read nonetheless.

Since you mentioned that you want to learn as much as possible, I wouldn't mind adding a few general references that will surely interest you. Try:

1. Courant and Robbins - What is Mathematics?
2. Ian Stewart - The Foundations of Mathematics
3. Ravi Vakil - A Mathematical Mosaic: Patterns and Problem Solving

In fact, it was largely thanks to Ravi Vakil's book that I decided to take up mathematics for my higher studies when I was completing high school.

All the very best.

Answer (score 1):

*Discourses on Algebra*, by Igor Shafarevich might be a good idea. At a more elementary level, you also have *Algebra*, by Israel Gelfand and Alexander Shen.